# Is there any opengl example so that I can run on MacOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

Is there any opengl example so that I can run on MacOS 10.5.5?
And if there is a XCode project with the opengl examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Check out these ones. They weren't easy to find :)

- [Example 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010104)
- [Example 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLSLBasicsCocoaDL/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004403)
- [Example 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004501)

Answer (score 5):

The Nehe tutorials will run on OS X.  Scroll to the bottom of each tutorial and you'll see a download link for about a dozen platforms / languages / IDEs, one of which is OS X / Objective-C / Cocoa.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch in /Developer/Examples/OpenGL.

Comment: I couldn't find that directory. In my iMac with OS X 10.8.4, with Xcode 4.6.3, I found examples scattered under /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/samplecode/XXX. With for example, XXX=GLFullScreen/GLFullScreen.zip, which I found pretty weird...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the examples that come with XCode that Brad mentioned, there is an OpenGL example in Aaron Hillegass's book *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X*.  All of the source code from that book is [available for download](http://www.bignerdranch.com/products.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend /Developer/Examples/OpenGL/GLUT

by learning openGL with GLUT you can very easily copy/paste arbitrary openGL code from the internet and have it compile and run properly.  (assuming it's also GLUT based-- but there's a ton of it out there...)

Dietrich is right, the nehe tutorials are very valuable, but for me many of them were far too game-oriented if not game-on-windoze-platform specific.

and of course, don't overlook:
[openGL.org code examples and tutorials page](http://www.opengl.org/code/)

Answer (score 0):

[Impromptu](http://impromptu.moso.com.au/downloads.html) is a live coding environment that handles openGL, check out this gentle 
[tutorial](http://homepage.mac.com/digego/opengl_one.mov).

Additionally, Impromptu has hooks into the Mac audio units and camera and is a great prototyping environment.

It does use Scheme, a language that may not be as wide spread; but it allows you to build up your program one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of sample code, demonstrating OpenGL and others, in the [Mac OS X Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) and these include all XCode project files needed.