# OpenGL Hello World on Mac without XCode

Tags: macos, opengl

I'm trying to write a hello world for OpenGL on Mac (Lion). I've found some [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924114/is-there-any-opengl-example-so-that-i-can-run-on-macos) or [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziBqnDY839U), but most of them require XCode. I'm OK with XCode, but I thought there should be some simpler approaches to write just a hello world, similar to write a .cpp file in vim under terminal, compile and run. (of course install libraries if needed beforehand)

Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using OSX I would highly recommend using XCode and use NSOpenGLView. [This](http://www.macopenglbook.com/) book  has a lot of material regarding the several APIs you can use. GLUT is definitely the quickest to get to grips with, and to set up.

If you want to use GLUT and compile at the terminal you could try this:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void display(void) {

    //clear white, draw with black
    glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 0);
    glColor3d(0, 0, 0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //this draws a square using vertices
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, 128);
    glVertex2i(128, 128);
    glVertex2i(128, 0);
    glEnd();

    //a more useful helper
    glRecti(200, 200, 250, 250);

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void reshape(int width, int height) {

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //set the coordinate system, with the origin in the top left
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, height, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void idle(void) {

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {

    //a basic set up...
    glutInit(&argc, &argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);

    //create the window, the argument is the title
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT program");

    //pass the callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glutMainLoop();

    //we never get here because glutMainLoop() is an infinite loop
    return 0;

}
```

and then compile with:

```
 gcc /System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/GLUT /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/OpenGL main.c -o myGlutApp
```

That should do the trick. I would say though don't try and fight XCode work with it, it will save you time and frustration.

Comment: I tried your method in terminal but get: hello.c:47:21: error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory

Comment: hmmm, i am running 10.6 (snow leopard) and it works. can you verify that you have GLUT on your system? have you installed XCode and Apple's developer tools?

Comment: It works after I change the include path from "GL/glut.h" to "GLUT/glut.h". Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use GLUT straight in Xcode, you just need to add the GLUT framework (works on 10.6).

Comment: It's sad when the OP question specifically states "without XCode" and the top answer and many comments say "use XCode" anyway. Some of us don't really care about GUI IDEs and developing apps for Mac--OSX just happens to be the platform we are using while practicing some coding.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit old but I'll answer it because I just learned how to do it. First there are two errors in the sample code above, they're easy to fix. On OS X 10.8 using clang this works.

```
clang++ -framework glut -framework opengl hello.cpp
```

The above code should compile. The signature of the main function is incorrect though.

```
<int main(int argc, char *argv)
>int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Which makes the `glutInit` wrong,

```
<glutInit(&argc, &argv);
>glutInit(&argc, argv);
```

The output sucks, but it makes a window and it shows how to use the frameworks with clang. Thanks for the starter file.

Comment: Ivan's fix worked for me, (OSX Mavericks). 
https://gist.github.com/omenking/35b920a1d2cbf99fc6f2
To run the a.out file just put /a.out in your command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GLUT and writing a small C++ program. You can use something like macports to install necessary libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 *  As a first example of using OpenGL in C,
 *  https://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/source/glut/first-triangle.c
 */
 
#include <GLUT/glut.h>   // freeglut.h might be a better alternative, if available.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(void) {  // Display function will draw the image.
 
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );  // (In fact, this is the default.)
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 ); // red
    glVertex2f( -1, -1 );
    glColor3f( 0, 1, 0 ); // green
    glVertex2f( 1, -1 );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 ); // blue
    glVertex2f( 0, 1 );
    glEnd();
    
    glutSwapBuffers(); // Required to copy color buffer onto the screen.
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {  // Initialize GLUT and
    ///GL 3D drawing
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);    // Use single color buffer and no depth buffer.
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);         // Size of display area, in pixels.
    glutInitWindowPosition(300,100);     // Location of window in screen coordinates.
    glutCreateWindow("Hello OpenGL"); // Parameter is window title.
    glutDisplayFunc(display);            // Called when the window needs to be redrawn.
    
    glutMainLoop(); // Run the event loop!  This function does not return.
                    // Program ends when user closes the window.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look online for the example/tutorial code of any book on OpenGL.  They all start with very simple programs that require at most GLUT (as mentioned by another poster), and generally have instructions on how to build them.  So just download one of these simple programs and get it up and running.